# Selecting items from a many to many field to link specific items in the list to a model in the admin panel

Tags: django, django-models, django-admin

I am working on a recipe book app, and I currently have my models connected in this way:

```
class Tool(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    description = models.CharField(max_length=200)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

class Recipe(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    description = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    servings = models.IntegerField(default=1, blank=False)
    tools = models.ManyToManyField(Tool)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name
```

The admin panel input currently looks like this:

[image]

Upon saving the data as shown in the screenshot, I get the following error:

```
OperationalError at /admin/recipeBook/recipe/add/
no such table: recipeBook_recipe_tools
```

Here is my admin.py, just incase it's useful:

```
from django.contrib import admin

from .models import Recipe, Ingredient, Instruction, Tool

# Register your models here.
class IngredientInline(admin.TabularInline):
  model = Ingredient
  extra = 2

class RecipeAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
  fieldsets = [
    ('Information', {'fields': ['name', 'description', 'servings']}),
    ('Tools', {'fields': ['tools']})
  ]
  inlines = [IngredientInline]
  list_display = ('name', 'description', 'servings')
  search_fields = ['name']
  list_filter = ['servings']

admin.site.register(Recipe, RecipeAdmin)
admin.site.register(Ingredient)
admin.site.register(Instruction)
admin.site.register(Tool)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have an error like this.

Make sure you migrate your database after adding to your models.